# string split at the last (also at any nth) delimiter in R and remove the string before the delimiter

Tags: r

I have a vector `vec`. I need to remove the part before last "/" and get the remaining string and get the `result`. Please also note that I can't use Perl-compatible regexps (i.e. perl=FALSE). I would also like to see it for the nth delimiter.

```
vec<-c("/apple/pineapple/mango/reg.sh_ttgs.pos","/apple/pipple/mgo/deh_ttgs.pos")
```

Result for the last delimiter

```
reg.sh_ttgs.pos , deh_ttgs.pos
```

Result for the 2nd delimiter

```
pineapple/mango/reg.sh_ttgs.pos, pipple/mgo/deh_ttgs.pos
```

and so on..

Comment: for the last part, you can use function `basename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to use a function like this (using `gregexpr` to get the location of a string and `substring` to subset the string accordingly):

```
get_string <- function(vec, n) {
  if(n == 'last'){
    positions <- lapply(gregexpr(pattern ='/',vec), function(x) x[length(x)] + 1)
  }else{
    positions <- lapply(gregexpr(pattern ='/',vec), function(x) x[n] + 1)
  }
  substring(vec, positions)
}
```

Output:

```
> get_string(vec, 2)
[1] "pineapple/mango/reg.sh_ttgs.pos" "pipple/mgo/deh_ttgs.pos"        
> get_string(vec, 'last')
[1] "reg.sh_ttgs.pos" "deh_ttgs.pos"
```

You either specify the nth '/' or just specify 'last' if you want just the last part of the path.

Note: I am using an `if-else` statement above just in case the position of the last '/' is different in the various elements of your actual vector. If the number of `/`s will always be the same across all elements only `lapply(gregexpr(pattern ='/',vec), function(x) x[n] + 1)` is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use `char2end()` in the `qdap` package. You specify a delimiter and which delimiter you want to use (1st, 2nd, etc.) in the function.

```
library(qdap)
```

For the 2nd delimiter,

```
char2end(vec, "/", 2)
#[1] "pineapple/mango/reg.sh_ttgs.pos" "pipple/mgo/deh_ttgs.pos"
```

For the last delimiter,

```
char2end(vec, "/", 4)
#[1] "reg.sh_ttgs.pos" "deh_ttgs.pos"
```

Comment: This is a nice one. Didn't know of its existence either. It has a very interesting source code too. Thanks.

Comment: @LyzandeR Yeah, the package offers various kinds of things. I cannot even go through the whole CRAN manual. Tyler created a great package.